# Backup exchange to PST without New-MailboxExportRequest

Tags: exchange, export, outlook

I've been tasked with archiving the contents of 300 mailboxes to PST on an Exchange 2010 environment. However, the exchange administrators are being annoyingly overprotective and not allowing me to use the New-MailboxExportRequest PS command to make the whole process a bit easier.

Short of manually setting up 300 outlook profiles and using "import/export" on each one, is there any way I can automate this task?

Comment: "exchange administrators are being annoyingly overprotective" <-- Get bosses involved. Also, if this is what I think it's for you should probably document every interaction with those administrator... CYA should the SHTF.

Comment: Obviously PowerShell *would* be the way to automate this. Personally I'd go back to whoever gave you the task and tell them that they can either make sure the Exchange admins give you the access you need to complete the job effectively, or if they actually have Exchange admins, get them to do it instead. (Seeing as I assume their job is to, you know, administer Exchange)

Comment: I couldn't agree more guys. Especially as the permission required doesn't appear to allow me to do anything other than archive mailboxes to PST....which I can do anyway in a longer drawn out way. HOWEVER, if there is a way to do this that would avoid confrontation, I think this would be the preferred method.

Comment: Pardon me for asking the obvious question, but if they won't even let you run `New-MailboxExportRequest`, what, if anything **will** they let you run?  And really, if they don't want you running it, tell them to run it themselves (or have a manager do that).

Comment: Well, I have access to the entire companies mailboxes, so I was hoping to put together something that would automate the process using only client commands. That way I could get the job done and also show the exchange admins how pathetic they were being.

Comment: Sorry for double post, but does anybody know of any IMAP utils that will export to PST? That might be another way around it.

Comment: paid solutions are there $$$$  https://www.veeam.com/wp-getting-best-availability-microsoft-exchange-veeam.html , yet they offer a free trial of 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

You can't Export Exchange to PST without using PowerShell New-MailboxExportRequest command as it is the only manual way to grant the permission related to import/export role to the Exchange User which you can see [here](http://lettoknow.com/export-exchange-mailbox-to-pst-powershell/) clearly in this informative blog.

a) Some external permissions are required to export exchange mailbox data.

**New-MailboxExportRequest - Role "Mailbox import export" - User "Admin"**

b) Run New-MailboxExportRequest cmdlet and export exchange Mails to pst via PowerShell
**New-MailboxExportRequest - Mailbox user -Filepath "\\Sharename\user.pst"**

Comment: pls consider adding the example in the answer itself.